# How to put multiple container elements next to the sidebar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having this issue where small squares wont be on top of the page and instead they are way below leaving a lot of white space above them. I tried make them **position: fixed;** but then everything is sliding of when you scrolling dawn on the page. How to fix this? I will attach HTML and CSS below
[image]

```css
.container1 {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
  margin: 10px;
}

.container-fluid {
  float: right;
  padding-left: 320px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.wrapper .sidebar {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a {
  color: black;
}

.sidebar ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.sidebar ul li a {
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar col-xs-0">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/listing">Listing</a></li>
      <li><a href="/listing">Listing</a></li>
      <li><a href="/listing">Listing</a></li>
      <li><a href="/listing">Listing</a></li>
      <li><a href="/listing">Listing</a></li>
      <li><a href="/listing">Listing</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="container1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"></div>
    <div class="container1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"></div>
    <div class="container1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"></div>
    <div class="container1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"></div>
    <div class="container1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"></div>
    <div class="container1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the grid system, and structure my html similar to this.

Not sure, which version of the Bootstrap you're using. but you will get an idea.

Here is an example for you: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/dashboard/

```css
.container1{
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
    margin: 10px;
}


.sidebar{
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    border: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
}

.sidebar ul li a{
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="sidebar col-2">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li><a href="/listing">Listing</a></li>
          <li><a href="/listing">Listing</a></li>
          <li><a href="/listing">Listing</a></li>
          <li><a href="/listing">Listing</a></li>
          <li><a href="/listing">Listing</a></li>
          <li><a href="/listing">Listing</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <main class="col-10">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="container1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"></div>
        <div class="container1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"></div>
        <div class="container1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"></div>
        <div class="container1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"></div>
        <div class="container1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"></div>
        <div class="container1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"></div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>  
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: good approach but still a little off because its on auto-fill not static 4 column layout

Answer (score 0):

You should learn more Bootstrap. When you are using Bootstrap, use its grid system correctly. (Or you just made a mistake in HTML semantics).

**Try this**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="sidebar col-xs-12 col-md-4">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/listing">Listing</a></li>
        <li><a href="/listing">Listing</a></li>
        <li><a href="/listing">Listing</a></li>
        <li><a href="/listing">Listing</a></li>
        <li><a href="/listing">Listing</a></li>
        <li><a href="/listing">Listing</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
      <div class="container1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
      </div>
      <div class="container1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
      </div>
      <div class="container1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
      </div>
      <div class="container1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
      </div>
      <div class="container1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
      </div>
      <div class="container1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And remove CSS declaration of `container-fluid`, and also `.container1` seems chaotic.

Try to use Bootstrap fully with him helpers and so on.

**Just study their web page.**

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="container1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"></div>
    <div class="container1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"></div>
    <div class="container1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"></div>
    <div class="container1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"></div>
    <div class="container1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"></div>
    <div class="container1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"></div>
  </div>
```

i would use a drop menu if you dont know how to use it here it is
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/

Answer (score -1):

in your code there is no parent of the wrapper

if  you use `display: flex` in the parent of your wrapper then it will work perfectly.

or use this

```
.wrapper,.sidebar{
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: He uses Bootstrap. Beside of that you could try to prove that your solution would work by using a code snippet. Which would also show then, that your idea wouldnt work.